# Word from .txt into arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm trying to put the words form the **in.txt** file into an array and display the word in alphabetical order. I know i have errors in my code. Pls help me!
First i display the words from the file one by line and that works.
But i have one error

> cannot convert char to char *
>   I've tried to chance

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
char c,s[20];
char *p,*d[20];
int i,x;
FILE *f;
f=fopen("in.txt","r");
if (f==NULL)
{
    printf("Erroe reading file\n");
    exit(1);
}
while(!feof(f))
{
    fgets(s,100,f);
    p=strtok(s," \n");
    while (p!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%s \n",p);
        p=strtok(NULL," \n");
    }
}


    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fgets(s,100,f);
        p=strtok(s," \n");
        while(p)
        {
            for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                strcpy(d[i],p);
                if(x=strcmp(d[i],d[i+1])<0)
                {
                    c=d[i];
                    d[i]=d[i+1];
                    d[i+1]=c;
                }
                else
            p=strtok(NULL," \n");
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("%s",d[i]);
}
```

Comment: If you don't want your question to be closed, specify what you need help with. For example, what happens when you compile? When you run (if you get to that point)? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried to do about it? Don't just ask people to fix your stuff for you. That being said, welcome to SO.

Comment: your algorithm is quadratic

Comment: @true i really doubt that is his worry :)

Comment: It looks like you have one word per-line from your code. Can you post a representative 3-4 lines of your `in.txt` file so we can confirm the format? Your `strtok(NULL," \n");` is ambiguous.

Comment: 1) `fgets(s,100,f);` but `char s[20];`

Comment: 2) `while(!feof(f))` but EOF occurs at `fgets(s,100,f);`. Executable statements after this becomes invalid EOF if happens.

Comment: 3) `strcpy(d[i],p);` A pointer of `d[i]` not pointed to ensured memory areas.

Comment: 4) `for(i=0;i<100;i++)` meaningless line.

Comment: _cannot convert char to char * I've tried to chance_ `c=d[i];..d[i+1]=c;` `c` is `char`, `d[i]` is `char*`. So type of `c` should be `char *c;`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 31
#define MAX_WORDS 128

#define S_(n) #n
#define S(n) S_(n)

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(*(char**)a, *(char**)b);
}

int main(void){
    char s[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
    char *d[MAX_WORDS];
    int i, n = 0;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen("in.txt", "r");//Error handling is omitted

    while(1==fscanf(f, "%" S(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "s", s)){
        if(n < MAX_WORDS)
            d[n++] = strdup(s);//make s's clone
        else
            break;
    }
    fclose(f);
    qsort(d, n, sizeof(*d), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n", d[i]);
        //free(d[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

fgets-strtok version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 128

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(*(char**)a, *(char**)b);
}

int main(void){
    char s[128];
    char *d[MAX_WORDS];
    int i, n = 0;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen("in.txt", "r");//Error handling is omitted

    while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), f)){
        char *p = strtok(s, " \t\n");
        while(p){
            if(n < MAX_WORDS)
                d[n++] = strdup(p);//make s's clone
            else
                goto out;
            p = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
    }
out:
    fclose(f);
    qsort(d, n, sizeof(char*), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n", d[i]);
        //free(d[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice enough to frame +1

Comment: http://s28.postimg.org/pm740ux7h/screen.png

Comment: http://s28.postimg.org/pm740ux7h/screen.png
This is a print screen of what i've want. Thx for your help by it's a little hard for me to understand I'll try..

Comment: @user3777978 Image is not large, such as can be determined.